# Get queryScope result trough whereHas method for calculating distance using haversine formula

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have Products model, Stores model, and Products belongsTo Stores,
in the stores model i have this:

```
public function scopeWithDistance($query,$lat,$lng){
    $q = $query;
    if($lat != 0 && $lng != 0){
        $raw = 'floor((floor(3959 * acos(cos(radians(:lat1)) * cos(radians(lat))
                * cos(radians(lng) - radians(:lng))
                + sin(radians(:lng2)) * sin(radians(lat)))
            )) * 1.609344) AS distance';

        return $query->selectRaw($raw, [
            'lat1' => $lat,
            'lng' => $lng,
            'lat2' => $lat,
        ]);
    }
    return $q;
}
```

I could easily get the Store Attrs plus the calculated distance with:

```
App\Store::withDistance(20.6008362,-100.3966416)->get();
```

in tinker.

But when i run a query trying to get that Store::withDistance through my Product model, it doesn`t return me the distance field :(

My query:

```
$query = Product::whereHas('mm_product')
        ->with(['media', 'category', 'master_category', 'store.user.user_data', 'store.user.media', 'tag'])
        ->whereHas('store', function ($q) use ($state_id, $shop_id, $lat, $lng) {
            if ($state_id && $shop_id == 0) {
                $q->where(function ($q) use ($state_id, $lat, $lng) {
                    $q->whereNotNull('lat')->whereNotNull('lng')->where('state_id', $state_id)->withDistance($lat, $lng);
                });

            }
        });
```

HELP ME PLEASE :'(

EDIT: Im doing it like this cause then i want to make an orderBy and Paginate over the results based on distance calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add your distance search function in eager load then it will return as  a filed. When adding to `whereHas` then it only filter the result. So better to reuse, you can do it like this

Define this function in `Store` model (I have changed the haversine code)

```
public static function haversine($coordinates)
{
    return '(6371 * acos(cos(radians(' . $coordinates['latitude'] . ')) 
    * cos(radians(`lat`)) 
    * cos(radians(`lng`) 
    - radians(' . $coordinates['longitude'] . ')) 
    + sin(radians(' . $coordinates['latitude'] . ')) 
    * sin(radians(`latitude`))))';
}

public function scopeWithinDistance($query, $haversine, $radius = 5)
{
    return $query->select('id', 'user_id')
                 ->selectRaw("{$haversine} AS distance")
                 ->whereRaw("{$haversine} < ?", [$radius])
                 ->orderBy('distance');
}
```

Now use it in your query like this

```
$haversine = Store::haversine(['latitude' => '20.6008362', 'longitude' => '-100.3966416']);

$query = Product::whereHas('mm_product')
        ->with(['media', 'category', 'master_category','store' => function($q) use($haversine){
             $q->selectRaw("*, {$haversine} AS distance");
         },'store.user.user_data', 'store.user.media', 'tag'])
        ->whereHas('store', function ($q) use ($state_id, $shop_id, $haversine) {
            if ($state_id && $shop_id == 0) {
                $q->where(function ($q) use ($state_id, $haversine) {
                    $q->whereNotNull('lat')->whereNotNull('lng')
                      ->where('state_id', $state_id)
                      ->withinDistance($haversine);
                });
            }
        });
```

It will give you the distance in miles, if you want it in kilometer then multiply it by `1.60934`

Comment: Awesome, thank you, also i got a better understanding of the scope func.

Comment: One question, any idea how to sort this by the actual distance calculation, and no just filtering them in the whereRaw